Android: Make app enter/exit fullscreen on demand
I am trying to write a function that allows the app to enter/leave full screen at any given time. So far I tried this:
    @ReactMethod
    fun onFullScreen() {
        UiThreadUtil.runOnUiThread(
            object : Runnable {
                @Override
                override fun run() {
                    currentActivity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE)
                }
            }
        )
    }


    @ReactMethod
    fun offFullScreen() {
        UiThreadUtil.runOnUiThread(object : Runnable {
            @Override
            override fun run() {
                currentActivity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (
                    ((View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN))
                )
            }
        })
    }

With this, I am facing two problems: The Layout shifts when I enter full screen, and the status bar stays black even though my app's background is white.
Beside this, this method seems to be deprecated, but I can't find any other working method in the docs.
How can I make this work? Is there a better or simpler way to achieve this?
